# Change a variable into another sub

Tags: vba

How to change the valor of an variable into another sub? Something like this.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim valor as Integer
    valor = 0
    Call Increment
    MsgBox valor 'expeted 30
End Main

Sub Increment()
    valor = 30
End Main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Public variables is to be limited to those cases where you can't rely on passing variables through subs or functions

In this case you can, so enhance your "changer" sub to accept an argument and have your main sub passing one to it:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim valor as Integer
    valor = 0
    Increment valor ' pass valor to Increment() sub (no need far "Call" keyword)
    MsgBox valor 'expected 30
End Main

Sub Increment(valor as Integer) ' have Increment accept an integer argument
    valor = 30 ' change the value of the passed argument
End Main
```

The argument type must be the same of the passed variable one (in this case: Integer) while the name must not, so the following is valid:

```
Sub Increment(myValor as Integer) ' have Increment accept an integer argument
    myValor = 30 ' change the value of the passed argument
End Main
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative - return the change through a function.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim valor as Integer
    valor = 0
    ' whatever code here
    valor = Increment(valor)
    MsgBox valor 'expected 30
End Main

Function Increment(ValueToBeIncremented as Integer) As Integer
    ValueToBeIncremented = ValueToBeIncremented + 30
End Main
```

Your original "Increment" routine did not actually increment, it set a value - so I made that modification here.

Comment: By far the cleanest approach.

Answer (score -2):

```
Public valor As Integer

Sub Main()

    valor = 0
    Call Increment
    MsgBox valor 'expeted 30
End Sub

Sub Increment()
    valor = 30
End Sub
```